# Accessing and manipulating resource files in Maven project

Tags: java, rest, maven, io

I know that there already are many questions on this topic, but none of them seem to help. In my Maven Project I am trying to access the src/main/resource files, and i know that during runtime when I want to read a file and write to it i must access its class path or something.

I am really not sure how that works, I managed to write code to read from a file, but I don't know how to write code that writes to a file. Here it is what i have so far:

```
    private File userFile;
    private ObjectMapper om;
    private InputStream is;

    public UserService() {
        om = new ObjectMapper();

        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("files/userJSON.json");

    }
```

This constructor represents the UserService class which methods I use to access User Resoruces located in userJSON.json file. Here is a method I use for reading a file:

```
public List<User> readJSON() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{


        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));


        List<User> list = om.readValue(br,new TypeReference<List<User>>(){});

        return list;
    }
```

How can I write to a file, and if possible to explain to me how this works. By that I mean how does Maven work with files during runtime and so on.

Comment: You can read from a resource from within the JAR file but writing into the jar file is simply not possible...If you need to write file use the home directory of user or something similar.Apart from that you wrote you `think it works` haven't you written some tests to proove that?

Comment: Why do you want to write to a resource file? What is really your goal?

Comment: Well i am building some kind of forum application, and i need users to register to the forum in order to use it, so whenever user registers i write his information in to the file so i can load it afterwards and use it to render the view ( i am using AngularJS )

Comment: For reading i just finished testing and it works . Edited the 'i think' part.

Comment: If you need a kind of persistence you need to think either about writing very simple into files or a kind of database (noSQL, SQL etc., Key-Value Store for example Redis etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call this method it will read the file and convert it to JSONObject:

```
private static JSONObject readUserJSON() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException {
        String jarPath = (new File("")).getAbsolutePath();
        JSONObject config = null;
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        config = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(jarPath + "resource/files/userJSON.json"));

        return config;

    }
```

ADD this dependency in .pom file:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple example</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Using below statement you get Absolute path of file and you can write it using file writer :

```
String jarPath = (new File("")).getAbsolutePath();
```